# Add New user permission in Subversion on Windows

Tags: svn, collabnet

I have Subversion installed on Windows (Collabnet Opensource Edition).

I'm unable to access it admin panel, and I need to add user & configure permissions for existing repository using command-line or some other utility as I'm unable to access its admin panel.

I'm unable to find the `svnaccess.conf` file. Can anybody tell me the location of the file? Also how to add new users?

Any link to do this operations using command prompt on Windows will be better.